# jQuery + chosen plugin: add url to selected option

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

This is probably easiest to explain if you just look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickcoxdotme/3cdPp/2/), which I've commented for clarity. Basically, I'm using Harvest's [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) plugin, and I'm just trying to make the 'go' button I've placed next to it a link for the `data-url` attribute of the selected option. I'm using the console heavily to try to debug, but I can't make it work.

I just want this to happen: When you choose an option from the chosen menu, the `href` of the go button becomes a link to that selection. Check out the fiddle and all will become clear.

Comment: upvote for showing me something new. The chosen is a cool plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your url selector to

```
url = $('#cancer-select option:eq(' + selectedIndex + ')').attr('data-url');
```

and removing the empty `<option>` tag surrounding your select options seems to fix it.

Edit from OP:

You also need to change your function to

```
$('#button-go').attr('href', '' + url);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nickcoxdotme/3cdPp/8/

Comment: I've made those changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/nickcoxdotme/3cdPp/5/ . But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah. I also had to make my last line `$('#button-go').attr('href', '' + url + '');`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickcoxdotme/3cdPp/7/). Will you add this to your answer and I'll mark it right? Also, will you explain the (' + selectedIndex + ') syntax? I've never seen that.

Comment: @nickcoxdotme Yes I was getting to that bit, I'll update my answer. The problem with the way you had that line is that it was within a string, so it was literally looking for an index of `'selectedIndex'` which does not exist, hence the `undefined` in the console

Answer (score 0):

Well it does not seem as though you can add a dataattribute and expect the chosen to carry it over to your new list. So I propose this: [Create an array of the urls before you make the chosen and stach the url by the option name.](http://jsfiddle.net/VxUbT/1/)

I added this:

```
var dataURLS = new Array();

var options = $('option');

options.each(function(){
    dataURLS[$(this).text()] = $(this).attr('data-url');
});
```

and changed this:

```
url = $('#cancer-select option:eq(selectedIndex)').attr('data-url');
```

to this:

```
url = dataURLS[$(this).text()];
$('.chzn-single').attr('href',url);
```

looking at the console output I think it does what you are after.

EDIT: Updated for accuracy.

Comment: The `href` attribute just says `javascript:void(0)`, and the console still says `url` is undefined...